# Azure pipeline fails with Warning MSB3246: Resolved file has a bad image

Tags: c#, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am unable to build with Azure a solution in .Net 5.0 that references a simple DLL, built in Any CPU / Release on a x64 machine with VS2019.
When it attempts to load the DLL, Azure complains :

> Warning MSB3246: Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is
> otherwise inaccessible. Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.dll' or
> one of its dependencies. **An attempt was made to load a program with an
> incorrect format**

The project works fine in local, both projects (the build DLL and the project that Azure have to build) are in .Net 5.0, default "Any CPU" configuration, with nothing special.
I would like to keep it in "Any CPU", without to have to define any custom build platform / configuration, as done on development machine.

Here's the (slightly simplified) beginning of the yaml pipeline file :

> trigger:
> - develop
>
> pool:   vmImage: 'windows-latest'
>
> variables:   solution: './Projects/**/*.sln'   buildPlatform: 'Any
> CPU'   buildConfiguration: 'Release'
>
> steps:
>
> - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
> - task: NuGetCommand@2   inputs:
>   restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
> - task: VSBuild@1   inputs:
>   solution: '$(solution)'
>   platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
>   configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

Is there a specific parameter to give to Azure to make it work with the simple already built "Any CPU" DLL ?

Comment: Is it useful to you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63787918/azure-devops-build-cannot-load-referenced-assemblies

Comment: Yes, thank you, LFS was enabled on the server and this is why the DLL were not properly loaded !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a YAML build, add [a checkout step with lfs set to true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#checkout-files-from-lfs):

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  lfs: true
```

Without it the file will be replaced with a placeholder to the lfs download location.

Here is the [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297607/vsts-hosted-agent-cant-load-dll-msb3246) you can refer to.

Comment: I was about to post it, the comment of @Jason Pan pointed me to the right direction and I just did it, now my build fails for other reasons but the DLLs seem to have been found and loaded as expected.